# WebPage font changing while opening in UIWebView within my app

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

My Application is using custom font ("Roboto"), I am opening a HTML page( this web page is also using Roboto font in CSS) in UIWebView within application, in which font of web page is bold.

can anyone help?, what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have following solution may be any one help you.

1) Add in .css and meta tags as follow.

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Never autoresize text */
}
```

and meta tags as follow

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;'>
```

2) You can also inject both into an existing website, using this javascript code as follow.

```
var style = document.createElement(\"style\"); 
document.head.appendChild(style); 
style.innerHTML = "html{-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}";
var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');
viewPortTag.id="viewport";
viewPortTag.name = "viewport";
viewPortTag.content = "width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);
```

and Use UIWebViewDelegate (`webViewDidFinishLoad`) method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    NSString *javascript = @"var style = document.createElement(\"style\"); document.head.appendChild(style); style.innerHTML = \"html{-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}\";var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');viewPortTag.id=\"viewport\";viewPortTag.name = \"viewport\";viewPortTag.content = \"width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;\";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement webView delegate and change font when load webView.

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
    //your code    
}
```